# PySide2 - Stylesheet is overriding BackgroundColor set from model (QHeaderView)

Tags: python-3.7, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I have a Stylesheet that implement a certain style for the QHeaderView:

```css
/* QHeaderView */
QHeaderView {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}
QHeaderView::separator {
    background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}
QHeaderView::section {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
QHeaderView::section:hover {
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
QHeaderView::section:horizontal {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical:first {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

QHeaderView[withCustomHeaders=true] {
    background-color: none;
}
QHeaderView[withCustomHeaders=true]::section {
    background-color: none;
}
```

But for a certain QTableView, I would like to change my headers colors. I tried

```py
self.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("")
```

also tried to add a custom property and set the `background-color` to `none` for this property in the stylesheet.
But the stylesheet would always override my data ...

```py
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if self.headers[section]["field"] == "field_to_color":
            return QColor("red")
```

I would like to know if there is a way to bypass this behavior or if I have to re implement the QHeaderView. Because if so, I loose a lot of built-in features

Edit 1: specify a section to color
Edit 2: we have a launch function, where the selected stylesheet is applied with

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(f"file:///{stylesheet.value}"))
```

Thanks !

Comment: Just set the specific stylesheet for *that* table

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. I would like to change the background of a specific cell through model. For example I put a "red" value but color is not hardcoded in the real project.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, sorry. Unfortunately, I'm afraid that that's not (easily) possible: whenever you set any background or border property of an item view with stylesheets, it *always* overrides the item background color (see [this related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/68166527)), so the only option left is to *not* use stylesheets for that header (you can set all other header view `::section` properties with the `[withCustomHeaders=false]` selector). The only other alternative is to subclass the header view and override `paintSection()`.

Comment: No worries, it's my fault, my explanations were not clear. So I'll go for a subclassification of QHeaderView. Thanks a lot for the answer!